# Solving system of integer solution

Tags: linear-algebra

First I want to know what is the logarithm used in the following system of equations.

> In the set-up protocol, $r_{0}^{\prime}, \cdots, r_{s}^{\prime}$ are found as a solution of the following system
> $$
> \left[\begin{array}{c}
> R^{\prime} \\
> \vdots \\
> R^{\prime}
> \end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
> r_{0}^{\prime} \cdot r_{1}^{\prime a_{1}} \cdot r_{2}^{\prime a_{1}^{2}} \cdots r_{s}^{a_{1}^{s}} & \bmod n^{2} \\
> & \vdots & \\
> r_{0}^{\prime} \cdot r_{1}^{\prime a_{s}} \cdot r_{2}^{\prime a_{s}^{2}} \cdots r_{s}^{a_{s}^{s}} & \bmod n^{2}
> \end{array}\right]
> $$
> The above system has $s+1$ unknowns and $s$ equations. Therefore it has one degree of freedom. To avoid the trivial solution $r_{0}^{\prime}=R^{\prime}$ and $r_{1}^{\prime}=\cdots=r_{s}^{\prime}=1$, we choose a random $r_{0}^{\prime}$. Then we divide the system by $r_{0}^{\prime}$ and we take logarithms to get
> $$
> \left[\begin{array}{c}
> \log \left(R^{\prime} / r_{0}^{\prime}\right) \\
> \log \left(R^{\prime} / r_{0}^{\prime}\right) \\
> \vdots \\
> \log \left(R^{\prime} / r_{0}^{\prime}\right)
> \end{array}\right] \quad \bmod n=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
> a_{1} & a_{1}^{2} & \cdots & a_{1}^{s} \\
> \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \\
> a_{s} & a_{s}^{2} & \cdots & a_{s}^{s}
> \end{array}\right] \cdot\left[\begin{array}{c}
> \log r_{1}^{\prime} \\
> \log r_{2}^{\prime} \\
> \vdots \\
> \log r_{s}^{\prime}
> \end{array}\right] \quad \bmod n
> $$
> The matrix on the right-hand side of the above system is an $s \times s$ generalized Vandermonde matrix (not quite a Vandermonde matrix). Hence, using the techniques in $[7]$ it can be solved in $O\left(s^{2}\right)$ time for $\log r_{1}^{\prime}, \cdots, \log r_{s}^{\prime} .$ Then $s$ powers modulo $n^{2}$ need to be computed to turn $\log r_{i}^{\prime}$ into $r_{i}^{\prime}$ for $i=0, \cdots, s$.

Second I want to understand how one can obtain integer values $r^\prime_1, r^\prime_2, ..., r^\prime_s$ after using logarithm.

Note: All the other values ($R^\prime,r^\prime_0, a_i;\forall i$) in the system are integers.

This equation is from [this article](http://crises2-deim.urv.cat/docs/publications/conferences/899.pdf) (page 16).

Answer (score 1):

It is a discrete logarithm with an unspecified base. Because it is a **discrete** logarithm it gives you integers. Some points follow.

First, you're following the math too linearly; you need to think from an implementation perspective. For example, you do not "obtain integer $(r_0', r_1', \dots r_n')$ after performing a logarithm" on them; instead you have a matrix equation which you are going to solve for integer $(\log r_0', \log r_1', \dots \log r_n').$ The logarithms in this expression are not logarithms that you actually have to take! Instead you simply have to *invert* them via modular exponentiation, which is much simpler.

That leaves the $r_0', R'$ thing for the only reason you'd like to choose a specific logarithm. I do not know the exact reasoning of the authors of the paper but I can tell you that there is one logarithm in particular which will give these some nice properties, and it is base-$n+1,$ but it is not perfect.

In particular, choose a random $R'$ coprime to $n$ and then choose a random $ 0 < b < n$ so that you choose therefore $r_0' = R' + b n \mod n^2$  from a smaller set of possibilities. This smaller-set-of-possibilities is the "imperfection" I mentioned above. However in the paper they only seem to require that the $r_i'$ be nontrivial -- so probably this is OK?

Then $R' / r_0' \equiv 1 \mod n,$ which means that you can efficiently calculate its base-$n+1$ logarithm in the mod-$n^2$ ring, because $(1 + n)^p = 1 + p n + O(n^2).$ So we compute the inverse element for the $r_0'$ that we've chosen above, and then multiply by $R'$, reduce modulo $n^2$, subtract 1, and divide by $n$. The resulting number is not $0$ so the resulting expression is not trivial.

Also, since multiplying by $(r_0')^{-1}$ was a permutation, I'm pretty sure that uniformly choosing $0 < b < n$ is the same as uniformly choosing $ 0 < p < n $ and working backwards from a known exponent, which is probably how they did this in practice.